# click command in selenium webdriver does not work

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

I have just recently done an export of my selenium IDE code to selenium web driver. I have found that a lot of the commands that worked in IDE either fail to work or selenium web driver claims to not support at all. So far I've been tackling these issues one at a time which is less than ideal...

Currently I'm working on finding out why clicking on a button does not work with web driver while it had previously worked in selenium IDE. My browser is FF 13 and my OS is Ubuntu.

Code Snippet

```
WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.name("submit"));
loginButton.click();
```

I had previously tried

```
driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
```

however the above line failed as well. The element is getting selected, however it does not log us in as I would like. I found other pages with similar problems, but their problem seemed to be with Internet Explorer not Firefox. I don't even want to think about the problems IE will give me down the road.

thanks,

P.S.
A tip on a better way to migrate from selenium IDE to Selenium Webdriver without losing all the tests I've written could solve this issue as well.

Comment: did you try to `assert loginButton.isDisplayed();`?

Comment: when you say the click() operation failed? Do you get any errors or exceptions.Please post them to understand why the click() operation fails.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you know for sure that the element is present, you could try this to simulate the click - if `.Click()` isn't working

```
driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: @PavelJanicek either one will do the trick but edited to show both ;)

Comment: wow. I did not know this. Upvote for teaching me something new :)

Comment: these commands worked for me. Though it turned out my problem was related to CAS authentication. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @TheLifeOfSteve Love it!  Even does this for elements outside the bounds of the screen!

Comment: @TheLifeOfSteve - Enter, Return, Space, JavaScript Executor, Actions - None of these work for me. It works if I put a small wait before my click. The element does not seem disabled. So, I dont know why a wait would be needed.

Comment: Caution: it will also execute the "click" if there is a popup window open, eg. if an error occurred. For that reason, I can't use this solution.

Comment: No idea why but in my case I had to combine click() with sendkeys() alone by themselves they didn't work. So first came click() then sendkeys()

Answer (score 10):

A major thing to watch out for is whether a button is Enabled or not.  You can still click them and nothing will fall over and the element is there but it is not ready to be clicked on so just doesnt do anything.

I've been using webdriver and its taken me most of the day to figure this out!

The following method seems to work reliably (in my environment for one button!)

```
    private void TryClick(By selector)
    {
        var wait = WaitUpTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible((selector)));

        //really important bit!
        WaitUpTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Until(d => element.Enabled);

        element.Click();
    }
```

you use it something like

```
TryClick(By.XPath("//button[contains(.//*,'Some Text')]"));
```

Answer (score 8):

`WebElement.click()` click is found to be ***not working if the page is zoomed in or out***.

I had my page zoomed out to 85%.

If you reset the page zooming in browser using (**`ctrl`** + **`+`** and **`ctrl`** + **`-`** ) to 100%, clicks will start working.

Issue was found with chrome version 86.0.4240.111

Answer (score 4):

Please refer here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6756
In crux

Please open the system display settings and ensure that font size is set to 100% 
It worked surprisingly

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with either version of your code. Whatever is causing this, that's not it.

Have you triple checked your locator? Your element definitely has name=submit not id=submit?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers everyone! I have found a solution, turns out I didn't provide enough code in my question.

The problem was **NOT** with the click() function after all, but instead related to cas authentication used with my project. In Selenium IDE my login test executed a "open" command to the following location,

```
/cas/login?service=https%1F%8FAPPNAME%2FMOREURL%2Fj_spring_cas_security
```

That worked. I exported the test to Selenium webdriver which naturally preserved that location. The command in Selenium Webdriver was,

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "/cas/login?service=https%1A%2F%8FAPPNAME%2FMOREURL%2Fj_spring_cas_security");
```

For reasons I have yet to understand the above failed. When I changed it to,

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "MOREURL/");
```

The click command suddenly started to work... I will edit this answer if I can figure out why exactly this is.

Note: I obscured the URLs used above to protect my company's product.

Comment: You said that it failed on IE not on firefox. Are you sure this situation only caused by location?

Comment: Please edit the original question instead of posting an update as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was using firefox and some reason, it was not taking the click command though from past 2months it was working.
My feeling was to make use of sendKeys and this page solved the problem. Now I am using sendKeys(Keys.Enter)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.  Why is this upvoted?

Answer (score 2):

This is [a long standing issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=628) with chromedriver(still present in 2020).

In Chrome I changed from a zoom of 90% to 100% and that solved the problem. [ref](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4075#issuecomment-358413015)

I find TheLifeOfSteve's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11688478/790198) more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I was working with EasyRepro, and when I debugged my code it was clicking on the element which is visible and enabled, and not navigating as expected. But finally I understood the root cause for the issue.

**My Chrome was zoomed out 90%**

Once i **reset the zoom level**, it clicked on the correct element and successfully navigated to next page.

Answer (score 0):

I use a function like below to make it work, or at least try a few times. Basically check the current_url until you get a new page.

def make_button_work(driver, path, max_try = 3):

```
strUrl_1 = driver.current_url
strUrl_2 = driver.current_url
try_num = 0
while strUrl_1 == strUrl_2:
    try_num +=1
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
    time.sleep(1)
    button.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    strUrl_2 = driver.current_url
    if max_try == try_num:
        print('Reached max_try')
        break
```