# Python Selenium click on element which loads after page load dyamically?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am using Python 3 and Selenium to automate browser activity.
On the page I am working on I have a button which when clicked loads a drop down menu. However upon inspecting I believe the dropdown menu is generated after the button is clicked as I do not see the html for the menu on page load.

I am using the following code

```
driver.get(path)
sleep(1)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id("DROPDOWN").click()
    sleep(8)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Account"]').click()
    print("button clicked")
except:
    print("no button to click")
sleep(1)
browser.quit()
```

The html

```
<button class="_19rM-p " id="DROPDOWN">
    <i class="_F-AgkVkVa  icon icon-menu"></i>
    <span class="_2Q7bh">Menu</span>
</button>
```

This menu is loaded after presumably via JS, the button I am trying to click is text Account

```
<div class="_2ID5Vy" role="menu">
    <div class="_2ID5Vy">
        <div class="_2pcjK9c" style="display: block;"></div>
        <div><span class="_4cdfLigUWzeeVcPzzbe78">User Menu</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="_49I5s">
        <button role="button" class="_2s6F0RequP0">Account</button>
    </div>
<div>
```

This loads up the website, and clicks on the dropdown menu. I see the button load in the drop down menu which I am trying to get the browser to click but it never does click. I am not sure what is causing this. It might be that the html is added after page load.

What can I do to click the button?

Thanks.

Edit
Updated code to include html.

Comment: Your XPath seems to work fine for that html and 8 seconds should be long enough. The only thing i could suggest is if [click isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676790/click-command-in-selenium-webdriver-does-not-work). Are you running selenium headless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.sleep` that you use may be not efficient enough.
Add explicit wait. For this import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And use this way:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("DROPDOWN").click()
account_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()="Account"]")))
account_btn.click()
print("button clicked")
```

Also, you can try clicking with CSS selector. For this button one of its options will be: ._2s6F0RequP0

```
account_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._2s6F0RequP0")))
account_btn.click()
```

Remember that your locators have to be unique. In your html code your locator is unique, but maybe on the page you are viewing are more buttons with such text.